# Angular2: Resolve a string to a pipe

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am looking to see if it is possible to take a string that represents the name of an angular pipe and resolve it in the template. For instance:

```
//Component:
pipe = 'date'

//Template
{{ pipe? ( somevalue | pipe ) : (somevalue) }}
```

In the example above, is there a way that I can resolve the string to an actual pipe that can be used in the template. Is there a better way to apply the pipe dynamically?

The use case here is letting the user of the component determine what kind of format to use for the value, if any.

**Update**

Ended up going with a custom pipe that accepts the pipe name to execute as a string, as well as any other possible formats for it. Here is a snippet, where pipe might be 'date' and format might be 'MM/dd/yyyy':

`{{ somevalue | applypipe: pipe: format }}`

I would then use some sort of mapping/factory for the accepted pipe name, create it and then run it's transform method.

Thanks for ideas!

Comment: Why not build a custom pipe which gets a service injected. That service could provide a method to vary the transform method based on your users selection/format.

Comment: So you are thinking that a value would be passed through a custom pipe and a custom pipe would return the value based on the input configurations or a service configuration: {{ somevalue | custompipe: pipe }} and then the custom pipe tries to map the string to an actual pipe, declare it, transform the value and return it. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Yes, seems you need some factory to resolve your pipe correctly. Dynamic component instantiation is not work properly so expect dynamic pipe instantiation too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help to get an idea..

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'anyPipe'
})
export class AnyPipe {
  public transform(val: any, arg: any) {
    return '!!' + val;
  }
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'dynPipe'
})
export class DynamicPipe {
  public transform(val: any, pipe: any) {
    if (!pipe) return val;

    switch (pipe) {
      case 'p1': return val + '-p1';
      case 'p2': {
        return new AnyPipe().transform(val, 'some args', 'maybe', '..');
      }
      case 'p3': return val + '-p3';
      default: return val;
    }
  }
}
```

live-demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/V64fok5eFeHAHz8DB6DJ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'cap'
})


export class CapPipe implements PipeTransform {


  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return value[0].toUpperCase() + value.substr(1, value.length);
  }
}


@Pipe({
  name: 'pip'
})

export class PipPipe implements PipeTransform {


  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
  }

  transform(value: any, pipeName: string): any {
    const pipe = this.injector.get<PipeTransform>(<any>pipeName, <any>{} );
    if (pipe.transform && typeof  pipe.transform === 'function') {
      return (pipe.transform(value));
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }

}
```

add the pipe 'cap' to provider list in the app module

```
providers: [
    { provide: 'cap', useClass: CapPipe },
],
```

use in template like so

```
{{title | pip: 'cap' }}
```